# Trouble hosting asp.net on xp iis

Tags: iis, firewall, hosting, asp.net, timeout

I'm doing some test hosting of an asp.net program I created

I can access it fine from the local machine (both debugging and pointing the virtual directory to it)

I can also access (local) by using the localhost or using the ip

however when i get on a different machine on the same network (i can ping my machine)

I get the following error:

```
Connection Interrupted

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.


The network link was interrupted while negotiating a connection. Please try again.
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Crash893

Edit:

Firewall is 100%default
nothing appears in the event logs under application,security or system

Comment: Have you tried disabling the firewall to make sure that it's not the firewall causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

firstly, look at your web.config file
verify whether everything is as it is supposed to be

next, check your iis manager
see if it allows connections from other machines
ip address should be 'all unassigned'
port - 80
what is the connection timeout? (default is 900)
is http keep-alives enabled?

Comment: where is that option?